# pyspark dynamic filtering

Tags: apache-spark, dynamic, filter, pyspark

Is it possible to dynamically filter dataframes?

For example, if I have the below dictionary with variable number of key value pairs, how can I filter the dataframe dynamically?

```
x = {
"date": "2018-10-01",
"color": "red"
}
```

I can do this

```
df.filter(df["date"] == x["date"] & df["color"] == x["color"])
```

But dictionary can have variable number of key value pairs, like also "shape": "circle" so I'd have to add to filter. Or if dictionary only had one kvp, it should filter on that one column only. Is there a way to build filter dynamically based on dictionary?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your logical operator is `AND`, you can simply create successively filtered data frames in a loop:

```
for col in x:
    df = df.filter(df[col] == x[col])
```

Comment: So simple, I overlooked it. Thanks!

Comment: what whould you recommend for OR? I cannot use spark.sql.

Comment: @BIDude The quick hack I can think of is `.where(' or '.join(["{col}='{val}'".format(col=col, val=x[col]) for col in x]))`. But that may pose a data type challenge if your columns aren't strings. One alternative I can think of is to rdd filter: `df.rdd.filter(lambda l: any([l[col] == x[col] for col in x])).toDF(df.schema)`

Comment: For OR, I like to use `df.filter(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, list_of_conditions))`